# Is the filtration of a process "evaluated" at a random time a sigma-algebra?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, random-variables, filtrations

Consider the stochastic process $(X_n)_{n\geq 1}$, defined by
\begin{align}
X_n = \sum_{k=1}^nY_k, \qquad Y_k= \left\{\begin{array}{ll} \mathcal{N}(0,1), &\; \text{w.p.} \; p \\
0, &\; \text{w.p.} \; 1-p\end{array}\right.
\end{align}
where the $Y_k$'s are independent, $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ is a standard normal random variable, and $0<p<1$.

Denote by $(\mathcal{F}_n)_{n\geq 1}$ the filtration generated by $(X_n)_{n\geq 1}$.

Next, define
\begin{align}
\tau_n = \sup\{k\leq n: Y_k\neq 0\},
\end{align}
so $Y_{\tau_n}$ is the last nonzero $Y$-variable observed before or at time $n$.

My question is: With respect to which filtration is the stochastic process $(Y_{\tau_n})_{n\geq 1}$ measurable?

Specifically, for a fixed value of $n$, is $\mathcal{F}_{\tau_n}$ a $\sigma$-algebra with respect to which $Y_{\tau_n}$ is measurable, or is it only correct to say that $Y_{\tau_n}$ is measurable with respect to $\mathcal{F}_n$?

Comment: How are you defining $\mathcal F_{\tau_n}$?

Comment: I guess that is the key step. Since $\tau_n$ is only $\mathcal{F}_n$-measurable, I'm starting to think $\mathcal{F}_{\tau_n}=\mathcal{F}_n$, making $(\mathcal{F}_n)_{n\geq 0}$ the smallest filtration such that $(Y_{\tau_n})_{n\geq 0}$ is adapted to it.

Comment: Yeah, I think I agree.  If we want $\tau_n$ and $Y_{\tau_n}$ to be $\mathcal F_{\tau_n}$ measurable, it looks like we would also have that $X_n$ is also $\mathcal F_{\tau_n}$.